# A UIButton under a view doesn't receive events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

An UIButton under three nested views doesn't receive events but if I put it one view above, it receives the events. This third view doesn't receive the events in any way, so I don't understand what element is capturing the events.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off `.userInteractionEnabled` for the view above the button.

Comment: I have tried to desactivated this flag but it doesn't work. In fact, the two first views has this flag activated and if I put the button below these two views, the button receive the events. ¿Is there any limitation about the number of nested views in order to propagate the touch events?